# Enumerability of real numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that the set of real numbers is not enumerable. However, is the set of **ordered pairs** of real numbers enumerable? Right now, my train-of-thought is like this: Since the set of real numbers is not enumerable, hence, since the ordered since the set $\mathbb R^2$ is a subset of the set of real numbers, the set $\mathbb R^2$ is not enumerable.

My question would be does being a subset of a non-enumerable set makes the set non-enumerable?

Comment: Assume reverse and get contradiction.

Answer (score 5):

$\Bbb R^2$ is most certainly not a subset of $\Bbb R$. However, the map $x\mapsto\langle x,0\rangle$ is an injection from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R^2$, so by definition $|\Bbb R|\le|\Bbb R^2|$, and therefore $\Bbb R^2$ is not enumerable.

If a set $A$ is a subset of a set $B$, the map $a\mapsto a$ is an injection from $A$ into $B$, so the cardinality of $A$ is **at most** the cardinality of $B$ and could be smaller. In fact it could be $0$: $A$ could be the empty set.

Possibly you meant to say that if $A$ is a **superset** of $B$, and $B$ is not enumerable, then $A$ is not enumerable; this is true, but it doesn’t immediately help you here, because $\Bbb R^2$ is not a superset of $\Bbb R$ (i.e., $\Bbb R$ is not a subset of $\Bbb R^2$). However, as I pointed out in the first paragraph, $\Bbb R^2$ does have a subset that is ‘the same size’ as $\Bbb R$, namely, $\Bbb R\times\{0\}$, and that works just as well.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have the right idea, but you're saying things backwards.

If $B$ is not enumerable (here $B$ should stand for "Big") then any *superset* of $B$ must also be big. That is, if $B \subseteq C$, then $C$ is not enumerable either.

However, we might have an enumerable set $S$ (for "Small") with $S \subseteq B$. As an example, think about $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

If I understand your idea correctly, you want to say that $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ (say, by looking at $\{(r,0)\}$) and thus since $\mathbb{R}$ is big $\mathbb{R}^2$ must be as well. That logic is correct!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 1):

*BEING*  a subset of an non-enumberable set does not make a set non-enumerable.

After all $\{1 \} \subset \mathbb R$ and $\{1\}$ is *certainly* enumerable.

But a set *HAVING* a  non-enumerable subset does make a set non-enumerable.

THis is because if a set in enumberable, every subset is enumerable. SO it is impossible for an enumberable set to have a non-enumerable subset.  So if a set *does* have an non-enumerable subset it can not be enumerable.

======

$\mathbb R^2$ is *not* a subset of $\mathbb R$ (I'm not sure why you think it is).

But $\{(a,0)|a \in \mathbb R\} \subset \mathbb R^2$.

And as $f:\mathbb R \to \{(a,0)|a \in \mathbb R\}$ via $f(x) = (x,0)$ is clearly a bijection.  [It's onto: for every $(a,0) \in \{(a,0)|a \in \mathbb R\}$ we can have $f(a) = (a,0)$. And its one-to one: if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $(x,0)=(y,0)$ and $x = y$] we have $\{(a, 0)|a \in R\}$ is non-enumerable.

And as $\mathbb R^2$ *has* an enumerable subset is can not be enumerable so it must be non-enumerable.